# Schemas of rest APIs

Tags: rest, schema

I am new to using REST APIs but I have seen that many systems which expose REST APIs do not provide the schema (structure) of the message that would be returned. Because of this, we cannot be sure on how exactly to parse the response. For example, an API call today might return a particular set of fields, and later some day, they might want to add another field in the response which might mess up my parser. So, If I were to parse a reply message of  a particular call, how can I do it the right way? How do the systems which expose these APIs process the calls internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why versioning was invented, if something major changed, a responsible provider will have a different version number for it.

This can happen to almost any library you use not just REST APIs.

Usual convention is to have your version numbering in the format `Major.minor.patch` ( see http://semver.org/ ).
 Anything that breaks backward compatibility should have a major version number. Of course not all maintainers follow this , follow it perfectly, if your provider(s) from whom you consume the API is poor in this you cannot do much.

What you can do is ensure you are implementing and managing your dependency versioning for all libraries including your API's well, know which version you wish to support use explict version based calls
instead of

```
http://example.com/api/customers/1234
```

use

```
http://example.com/api/v3.0/customers/1234
```

and keep track of dependencies for your project, also keep track of the documentation of the provider for updates, see if this will affect you in anway

Regarding API's being in schemaless formats  while new fields may not create problems, removing existing ones, or changing presentation, logic etc will break your code in ways difficult to debug, the changes maybe subtle.

Once a provider i was using changed field to all lowercase and didn't inform me, my application was expecting unique values for the field, but was getting similar values in some rare cases, it took me days to figure out where and what happened,

Answer (score 0):

Many REST services uses JSON as a base format for encoding data. Clients should simply ignore properties they do not know in the JSON response, thereby allowing the server to evolve its output over time (given that the server doesn't rename or delete properties). REST service versioning is a whole discussion on its own (try searching for it).

So in short - new fields should not mess up your parser, it should simply ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most good ones do! see for e.g - OpenStack REST APIs. Also, please note that the response being returned is for that particular version of the API, i.e, if you use the 
API (say):

```
/api/v1.0/interfaces/interface
```

and, you might get some fields like:

```
{ "name : "eth0",  "ip" : "10.1.1.1" }
```

Now, the API might evolve, and there could be a `1.1` version, which adds a few fields (retaining backward compatibility). I.e, `/api/v1.1/interfaces/interface` might return:

```
{ "name : "eth0",  "ip" : "10.1.1.1" , "mtu" : 1500 }
```

or a `2.0` which has a completely different structure, breaking backward compatibility:

```
GET /api/v2.0/interfaces/interface 
...
{ "interface" : { "name : "eth0",  "ip" : "10.1.1.1" , "mtu" : 1500 }}
```

again, all these have to be well documented!

And, the code using the APIs, *must* be aware of the versions they are interested in, and parse the response accordingly.

The *format* of the response, BTW depends on the kind of request you make, for e.g, if you se the Accept-encoding to JSON (`Accept: application/json`), the returned response must be in JSON - so you know which parser to use.

HTH